# localized human readable file size

Tags: python, localization

What would be the best way to display a file size in a human readable form (for instance `2000` as `2KB`) for the current locale (for instance, if the locale is `fr`, `2000` is displayed as `2Ko` instead of `2KB`) in python ?

It is really easy to do that in English with a few lines of code. Doing the same in various languages is the difficult part and it would be great to have a well maintained module on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) doing exactly that but I did not find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Babel`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Babel) library:

```py
>>> import babel.units
>>> babel.units.format_unit(2000, "digital-kilobyte", locale="fr_FR", length="short")
'2\xa0000 ko'
>>> babel.units.format_unit(2000, "digital-kilobyte", locale="en_GB", length="short")
'2,000 kB'
>>> babel.units.format_unit(2000, "digital-kilobyte", locale="fr_FR", length="narrow")
'2\xa0000ko'
>>> babel.units.format_unit(2000, "digital-kilobyte", locale="en_GB", length="narrow")
'2,000kB'
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, with documentation http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/units.html Thanks !